# WSDL file to host in IIS (WCF4)

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, wsdl

I'm a newbie with WCF and all the SOA dev.
I read and learn WCF and I understand more or less how it work

My problem is I have to develop a Webservice for a project. Nothing really complicated. 
This service will be hosted in IIS.
Some colleauges sent me a WSDL file to create my webservice.

But at the same time, we have to demade access to another company to allow the http connection from outside to our servers

A colleague of mine told me I have just to create a "blank wabeservice"

So Is it possible from the WSDL file and VS2010 to generate an "empty" WCF service? 
or is it possible to host the WSDL directly in IIS

My purpose is the send and address to my colleagues like "http://10.2.3.5/myservice.wsdl" and they'll be able to see the WSDL remotly

Thanks for your help

Regards;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a WSDL, you can [generate a service interface](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnetinterop/archive/2008/09/24/wsdl-first-development-with-wcf.aspx). You'll then have to implement the service yourself, which you in turn can host in IIS.

This service will emit its own WSDL, based on the interface again. Please note the exposed WSDL may differ from the one used to generate the service.